# Как получить данные для документа из другого справочника?

Tags: 1с

Имеется справочник "Контрагенты" и документ "ЗаписьНаТестДрайв".
"Контрагенты" имеет реквизиты: ФИО, "Паспортные данные", мобильный телефон.
Как мне при выборе клиента на форме документа "ЗаписьНаТестДрайв" заполнить автоматически поля ФИО, "Паспортные данные", мобильный телефон?
Я смог поставить ссылку на справочник, но как оттуда взять все данные, а не только имя?[image: справочник и форма]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Двойной щелчок по полю ФИО (то, что выделено сейчас на скриншоте), откроется панель свойств, внизу ищем событие ПриИзменении, нажимаем на увеличительное стекло справа. Откроется модуль формы с заготовкой процедуры. Нам нужно написать в ней код, который заполнит нам нужные поля. Т.к. событие выполняется на клиенте, реквизиты других объектов (в данном случае элемента спр-ка Контрагенты) нам недоступны, поэтому мы должны написать функцию, выполняющуюся на сервере и вызвать её. В итоге будет вот так:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ФИОПриИзменении(Элемент)

    ЗаполнитьДанныеКонтрагентаНаСервере();

КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Процедура ЗаполнитьДанныеКонтрагентаНаСервере()

    Объект.СерияПаспорта = Объект.ФИО.СерияПаспорта;
    Объект.НомерПаспорта = Объект.ФИО.НомерПаспорта;
    // и так далее, все нужные поля

КонецПроцедуры
```